# How to code sign using .Pem file?

Tags: windows, linux, visual-studio-2010, code-signing, pem

I am trying to code sign my application components using a digital certificate. The certificate format is .Pem

I referred the below url and try to implement the code signing using the Visual Studio SignTool.exe

[CodeSign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bin\signtool.exe"  sign /d "C:\\Users\\hpara\\Desktop\\SignCert\\Test.exe"  /f "C:\\Users\\guest\\Desktop\\SignCert\\Test.pem"SignTool
```

Signtool.exe returned the error : "Error: Missing filename.".

**Question:**

1. Can I sign the code using signtool.exe and .pem file?

My actual build environment is on Linux.  Just for testing purpose, I copied the certificate file to Win 7 computer and tried to sign the application using visual studio signtool.exe.

The **signing certifictae request (csr)** is generated on  Linux machine. Finally I need to sign the application on Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to codsign using the Pem file ?

**Solution:**

Step 1: Generate .pfx file from the .Pem File

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey MyprivateKey.key -in MyCertificate.pem -export -out MyCert.pfx
```

Step 2: Sign the code using .pfx file (Ex: Microsoft SDK SignTool.exe)

```
signtool sign /f "MyCert.pfx" /p password /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll "myapp.exe"
```

Comment: Where did "myprivatekey.key" come from?